# Displaying a small double in in decimal, not scientific format C++ /CLR

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I have doubles like `0.00006` which when displaying switch to the scientific format (something like `6E-05`).
I tried `Math::Round(doublenumber, 5)` but it cant round numbers smaller than `0.0001`. So rounding `0.00016` works fine, but `0.00006` doesnt, I want to print 0.00006 and not the scientific number in my form.
Any help?

Comment: See `ostream` manipulator [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: `std::fixed`+ `std::setprecision` could work?

Comment: See also the `ostream` manipulator [`setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) or the `ostream` method [`width`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width)

Comment: Read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip

Comment: The return value of Math::Round() does not have a format.  You don't get one until you convert it to a string.  Avoid getting confused about the way the debugger displays a floating point value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Double.ToString(String^)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) with the ["F" format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString). This forces the fixed-point format to be used.

My test program:

```
int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    double d = 0.00006;
    Debug::WriteLine(d.ToString("f")); // Uses the default precision value, 2
    Debug::WriteLine(d.ToString("f5"));
    Debug::WriteLine(d.ToString("f9"));
    Debug::WriteLine(d.ToString("f99")); // Highest supported

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0.00
0.00006
0.000060000
0.000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```